# Daylight Saving time

Tags: sql-server-2008, timezone, backup, netbackup

In my environment, there are servers running on native backup and Ola Hallengren plans. Our servers are a combination of 2008, 2012 and 2014. All the full backups are taken at 12am and log backups are taken every 15 minutes.

I have never accounted for Daylight Saving time before, so please tell me what adjustments I should make.

Will the 12am full backups be affected and what happens to the log backups?

Comment: Quite frankly I would run my servers in UTC.

Comment: Ours are CST unfortunately

Comment: Sure, but to be fair, that's not hard-coded on the motherboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server expert [Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/about/paul-s-randal/) addresses this very topic in [How does daylight savings time affect disaster recovery?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-does-daylight-savings-time-affect-disaster-recovery/).  It's a relatively short post, so I'm quoting it in its entirety.  Since you were concerned about your transaction log backups, I also highlighed a bit of the post to draw that to your attention.

> It’s common knowledge that SQL Server copes with daylight savings time
>   (DST) correctly so why should you care?
>
> Well, it’s not so common knowledge that at the end of DST when the
>   clocks go back an hour (always at 02:00 in the U.S.), SQL Agent
>   essentially pauses for an hour (in at least SS2000 onwards). This
>   means that if you have a job that’s doing something every 15 minutes,
>   there will be a gap of 75 minutes between the job execution at 01:45
>   and the job execution at 02:00. This happens because at 02:00, the
>   time is set back to 01:00 but the next run time of all the jobs
>   remains the same – so your job cannot execute until it’s next
>   scheduled time of 02:00. So, in the northern hemisphere every Fall,
>   and in the southern hemisphere every Spring, you lose an hour’s worth
>   of SQL Agent jobs. Still, why should you care?
>
> Well, it depends what the jobs are that get delayed by an hour. **If you**
>   **have a job that takes a log backup every 15 mins then on the day DST**
>   **ends, there’s actually a gap of 75 minutes between log backups. If you**
>   **have a Service Level Agreement (SLA) that limits the maximum amount of**
>   **lost work to 15 minutes in the event of a disaster, then for those 75**
>   **minutes you’re exposed to potentially not being able to meet that SLA!**
>
> That could be a pretty big deal, especially if something goes wrong
>   during that hour (no more or less likely than something going wrong at
>   any other time, but still possible). In that case, you need to come up
>   with an alternative solution. A couple of ways to get around the
>   problem I can think of:

- Have someone stay up late during that hour and take manual log
  backups.
- Switch over to database mirroring, which continually streams the log
  to the redundant server and so isn’t affected the DST issue.

> Both of these are viable solutions but I think the best one is to
>   create a SQL Agent job that runs at 01:59 and creates extra backup
>   jobs to run at 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, and 01:45. I don’t see why this
>   shouldn’t be possible. At 10:36 this morning I created a simple agent
>   job to print the date to a file and set it to execute at 09:40 – in
>   the past. I then set my system time back one hour and the job executed
>   perfectly. The only downside of this solution is that you need to
>   create and schedule the extra jobs using the T-SQL Agent SPs embedded
>   in job steps for your 01:59 job – tedious but not hard. Maybe someone
>   could send me a script and I’ll blog it as a follow-on?
>
> So with DST coming to an end on November 4th this is definitely
>   something for you to be aware of even if you don’t want to go to the
>   trouble of coping with the extra hour’s exposure. As an aside – the
>   dates when DST starts and ends changed this year. KB article 931975
>   discusses which parts of SQL Server aren’t aware of the changed dates
>   and what you can do about it.

Comment: So I could see a potential data loss for 75 minutes...If I am ok with that do i need to change any setting sor I can leave it as is

Comment: If you're ok with the potential of losing the 75 minutes until the next regularly scheduled log backup, then I don't think you need to make any changes.

Comment: Moreover the server that I am worried is an always on availability group so i guess if anything goes wrong i can switch over.

Comment: @SqlNovice assuming your availability group is on two servers that are not impacted by the same event, and that all events have committed to the other instance(s) = True.  You might be taking more for granted that is safe to assume.  PS servers are not in Availability Groups, databases are. (i.e. ""the server that I am worried is an always on availability group)

Comment: Sorry my mistake the databases in availability group are one replica is syn mode and another in  asyn mode

Comment: Sorry had to continue again...For example my T log runs at 1 am 1.15 am 1.30, 1.45 am and 2. am, since the server wont reach at 2 so it will go back to 1 am . So when it reaches 1 am will it execute the job at 1 am which it  previously ran or it wont execute any jobs from 1 am till 1.59 am and execute at 2 am .....Will I see any job failure ?

Comment: @SqlNovice - After a successful run at 1:45am, the next scheduled time to run will be 2am - that's where the missing 75 minutes that Paul Randal was talking about come into play

Comment: So nothing will run from 1 am till 1.59 am...it pauses and wont get any job failure error ?

Comment: That job will not run again until 2am, so there should be no possibility of a failure between 1am and 1:59am.

Comment: Thanks again....Just wanted to make sure....dont want to mess with my first job...thanks again